# How to animate UINavigationBar backgroundImage during pop

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swift3

I am trying to animate the backgroundImage of a navigation bar during a pop transition.

I realize backgroundImage is not an animatable property, but I've been able to achieve this during push by using a CATransition in the viewWillAppear method of the view controllers I'm transitioning between:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let animation = CATransition()
    animation.duration = 0.3
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade

    navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navigationBarBackgroundImage, for: .default)
}
```

I expected this to work during pop as well, but instead what happens is the navigation bar suddenly displays the background image for the next view controller (not animated) AFTER the pop animation is complete.

I've also tried combining the above attempt with a transition coordinator, but it yields the exact same results where the image suddenly changes after the pop is complete.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { [weak self] (context) in
    let animation = CATransition()
    animation.duration = 0.3
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade

    self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(navigationBarImage, for: .default)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Specifically I'm looking for a way to do this that works on iOS9 and iOS10.